# Is "void* p = &p;" legal in C?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I'm writing some list library as an exercise in C.
I wonder whether C specification allows that the declaration of a variable and the reference to it at the same time, like:-

```
typedef struct _List {
    int value;
    struct _List* next;
} List;

List* TERMINATOR = {0, &TERMINATOR};
```

In short, is it possible to write `void* p = &p;` ?

It seems `gcc` allows this, but I want to know how the specification is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to assign a `List` to a `List*` in your code, this cannot compile.

Comment: [gcc does not allow this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/17fni0JbaZd9vLwF), you can not initialize a pointer like you would initialize a struct it points to.

Comment: This is my stupid typo. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
void *p = &p;
```

is valid. Variables are in scope in their own initialization.

However,

```
List* TERMINATOR = {0, &TERMINATOR};
```

is not valid because `TERMINATOR` is a pointer here, not a struct.

If you remove the `*`,

```
List TERMINATOR = {0, &TERMINATOR};
```

is valid.

---

Reference: ISO 9899:1999, **6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers**:

> 7. Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of
>      the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that
>      begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any
>      other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.**

(Emphasis mine).

In `void *p = &p`, the declarator is `*p`.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is perfectly legal:

```
void* p = &p;
```

`p` identifier is in scope inside its initialization block, so it is perfectly legal to take its address.

Note that although this is allowed, it's highly unconventional. The most common way by far to terminate a list is to set `next` pointer to `NULL`.